# I have lost sound on my Linux profile. The icon has disappeared and the settings are greyed out

Tags: linux, audio

I have no sound on my profile on my Linux work computer.

Operating system:CentOS Linux 7.4.1708 Core(x86_64).
Cinnamon Version 3.6.7

If a different user logs onto computer, they have sound, but on my profile there is no sound.

The sound icon which is normally down in the bottom control panel has disappeared.

When I got to settings/output/sound/device settings, the volume bar is greyed out, and cannot be changed, The balance, fade and subwoofer bars can be moved, but change nothing as there is no sound output at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using it, did you try to execute a `pulseaudio -k`?

You don't need to restart pulseaudio, because it auto-restarts.

Comment: [fhaubrich@harkonnen ~]$ pulseaudio -k                                          E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process

Comment: @Frankie It doesn't sound like you are using pulseaudio then. You should be able to get some more info for troubleshooting by executing: `lspci -nn | grep Audio` and `lsmod | grep snd`.  And, hopefully not a hardware issue in something. Could be that too.

Otherwise, I'd suggest live booting a couple other distros and see if sound works, that way you'll know for sure it's not hardware.